# C# Open Workbook Returns Addin not Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, com, add-in

I am having a strange error, it was working a few days ago, I'm not sure what changed.

I'm using the  Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library (version 1.7) and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace.

when I run the following lines of code

```
EXCEL_APP = new Excel.Application();
currentIR = EXCEL_APP.Workbooks.Open(irFilePath);
```

When I look at the object currentIR is set to an add-in that is on my computer and not the workbook (given in the file path);

Has anyone had something like this happen?

[image: Workbook Object is Add-in]

I can give more details as needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer why the issue was happening, but I got around it by first opening the workbook, then setting my workbook object equal to the open workbook.

```
EXCEL_APP.Workbooks.Open(irFilePath);
string irName = Path.GetFileName(irFilePath);
currentIR = EXCEL_APP.Workbooks[irName];
```